# Why can't i fetch data from my database in mongodb nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to make a simple login system with mongodb.
Connecting works fine, but when i try to get the password:

```
async function getAdminPassword(username) {
    const query = { username: username }

    // console.log(admins)
    const user = await admins.findOne(query);

    try {
        return user.password
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

}
```

It will give this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null
    at getAdminPassword (C:\Users\isaia\programing\stinkysocks\chat\script.js:44:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Here is my database, in case anyone wants it:
[image: a part of my database]

Why doesn't this work? Thanks in advance!

By the way, this is just a test. Please don't tell me to hash my passwords, i know i should.

Comment: user could not be found. so the user becomes null

Comment: passwords should be hash:ed and not saved in plain text

Comment: What resources you are using to learn about authentication systems? Whatever it is, it should state in bold red giant letters that **you must not store passwords in plaintext ever not even as a joke**, don't think you can "learn about it" later, even more because it's a matter of using whatever library your framework exposes to do this. About your question, your code seems fine, maybe there's a typo on your `username` field inside your query.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really say much since the source code you provided are bunch of snippets here and there.

But looking at the error, it means the model you are querying for using `username`, it is null which means either the value for username is not defined or the username cannot be found in the collection.

What do you get when reading the value of `req.body.username` ?

**UPDATE**

This is just an example of how you could adapt to your code. I am not sure how you get the request but you can refer to mine here.

```
const Admin = require('../models/admins'); // This is import the model

exports.getAdminAccount = (req, res, next) => {
    const adminUserAccount = req.body.username;
    Admin.findOne({username: adminUserAccount})
        .then(adminUser => {
            // you can do your login functions here
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // you can do your login functions here for error
        });
};
```

If you want to keep the getting function to get user account separately then, you could try this.

```
const Admin = require('../models/admins'); // This is import the model

async function getAdminPassword(username){

    const adminAccount = await Admin.findOne({username: username});
    if(!adminAccount){
        // your logic here if not account exist
        return;
    }

    //your logic here if account exists
    const adminPassword = adminAccount.password;
    return adminPassword;
}
```

If it's still not working, like I mentioned you can console log `username` that you are passing to the function and see what you get. Then check if the username exists in the collection.

I suspect the username you are passing is somehow incorrect.

Apart from that, please hash your password when saving in db.

Comment: @isaiahday,  please check and let me know if it works. If not, you could you add in the output you get when console logging the (username) param?

Comment: It does work. The username is still isaiah08, and it does not find the user.

Comment: This is weird because it should work as if the username exists in the record. Could you check what is being output when you query the user const? 

The line here in your code: `const user = await admins.findOne(query);` Could you log whats the result of the const?

Comment: The user variable is just null.

Comment: In that case, could you do this and see what you get `const user = await admins.find();`

Comment: It's to big to fit in a comment, here's a link to the document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UriCOK5mX_nfUn3jtHAy7jKZLekQk8RnOo2NLEZKV5k/edit

Comment: I took a look at the output but seems it is not showing the documents but rather the Cursor itself. I could only advice you to debug this by actually passing the username value and see if you get any valid output.  `const user = await admins.find({username: 'isaiah08'});` If this also do not correctly display the password field then you have to check if the document exist in the collection or if you using the correct collection.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:
Turn on your MongoDb locally.

1. make sure your application is connected to db/ the username you are
   looking for exist in your DB.( Do not forget to import the schema you are using `const admins= require('./models/yourAdminsModelJs')`)
2. probably your function with return `Promise { <pending> }`, its
   because promise will always log pending as long as its results are
   not resolved yet. You must call .then on the promise to capture the
   results regardless of the promise state (resolved or still pending)

your full code:

```
const admins = require('./models/adminsModelJs')
..
..
..
async function getAdminPassword(username) {
    const query = { username: username }
    // console.log(admins)
    const user = await admins.findOne(query);
    // console.log(user)
    try {
        // console.log(user.password)
        return user.password
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

const result = getAdminPassword("someExample")
console.log(result)

result.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result) // "someExample password"
})
```

I am a litle bit suspicious about the way you are saving the password, consider using encryption algorithm.

Do not forget to set to username **unique : true** when creating the Schema.